# Building a type off keys of a const in Typescript

Tags: typescript

[image]

I have a dictionary of `MessageTemplates` which I'm building up over time and I was hoping that I could then export a *type* in TypeScript which represents the set of properties hanging off the `MessageTemplates` structure but it's objecting.

Feel like I'm doing something silly but I've been looking at this too long not to ask.

> Note, I did just figure out that if I use a **Class** structure -- with static methods hanging off of it -- it does work but I'm still baffled why the plain object literal syntax doesn't work.

Comment: `MessageTemplates` is a value, not a type.  You want `keyof typeof MessageTemplates`.

Comment: Ahhh yes. Damn wish I'd grokked that but almost as happy that you were there to point me in the right direction. If you write as an answer I'm happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're having is `MessageTemplates` is a *value*, not a *type*, and the [`keyof` index type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) acts on the name of a *type*, not a *value*.   One heuristic for telling the difference is to figure out if the name will appear in the compiled JavaScript or not.  If it appears at runtime, it's probably a value; if not, it's probably a type.  In your case, `MessageTemplates` will exist as a variable at runtime, so it's a value.

What you want to apply `keyof` to is not `MessageTemplates`, but the *type* of the `MessageTemplates` value.  And luckily you can use the [`typeof` type query operator](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript#typescripts-type-queries) to get the type of a value.  So `typeof X` for a value named `X` returns the type of that value.

(This is not to be confused with the [runtime `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), where `typeof X` acts on a value named `X` and returns a string like `"number"` or `"boolean"` at runtime.  You can tell which is which from context.  If `typeof` will appear in the compiled JavaScript, it's the runtime operator.  If `typeof` is part of a type annotation or declaration and gets erased before compiling to JavaScript, it's the type query operator.  I'm sorry; using the same keyword for different things is confusing, but that's the way it is.  I guess the language designers prefer to reuse already-reserved keywords so they don't end up breaking existing JavaScript code.  Or they think it's fun to make people add all these caveats to their explanations.)

To recap: you don't want `keyof MessageTemplates`, but "`keyof` *the type of* `MessageTemplates`", which is `keyof (typeof MessageTemplates)`. You can remove the parentheses: `keyof typeof MessageTemplates`:

```
export type IMessageTemplateType = keyof typeof MessageTemplates
// type IMessageTemplateType = "upcomingUpload" | ...
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!